# Clear Collection View Cells when new ones are generated (iOS7 - AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, json, uiscrollview, afnetworking, uicollectionviewcell

I have a Collection View Controller with Cells that get their content from a JSON call. Each Cell has a Scroll View (an image slideshow). I noticed that the slideshows are being loaded on top of the old ones (I could see the slideshow from the old cells appear right before the new slideshow is loaded). Or if I swipe to let's say the third image of my first cell and then scroll the fourth cell, it shows my the third image (instead of the first), but the Page Control will show that that's the first slide.

How can I "clear" the old cells (or at least clear the Scroll View, or stop it from being reused) while the new ones are being generated?

Article.h (NSObject)

```
@interface Article : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSURL *imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;

+ (void)latestNewsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *news, NSError *error))block;

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface ArticleImage : NSObject

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) NSURL *URL;

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;

@end
```

**Article.m (NSObject)**

```
@interface Article ()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSURL *URL;
@end

@implementation Article

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:attributes[@"url"]];

    NSMutableArray *mutableImages = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *imageAttributes in attributes[@"photos"]) {
        NSDictionary *imageFileAttributes = [imageAttributes valueForKeyPath:@"photo_file.photo_file"];
        ArticleImage *image = [[ArticleImage alloc] initWithAttributes:imageFileAttributes];
        [mutableImages addObject:image];
    }
    self.images = mutableImages;

    return self;
}

- (NSURL *)imageURL {
    return [[self.images firstObject] URL];
}

+ (void)latestNewsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *news, NSError *error))block {
    [[DeadstockAPIManager sharedManager] GET:@"articles" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableNews = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *attributes in JSON[@"articles"]) {
            Article *news = [[Article alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
            [mutableNews addObject:news];

            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        }

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

        if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableNews], nil);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (block) {
            block(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface ArticleImage ()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSURL *URL;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSURL *thumbnailURL;
@end

@implementation ArticleImage

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributes valueForKeyPath:@"thumb.url"]];

    return self;
}
```

**Collection View Controller**

```
- (void)setLatestNews:(NSArray *)latestNews {
    _latestNews = latestNews;

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)loadData:(id)sender {
    [Article latestNewsWithBlock:^(NSArray *news, NSError *error) {
        self.latestNews = news;
    }];
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ArticleCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ArticleCell"];

    [self loadData:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"articleCell";

    ArticleCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.article = [self.latestNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Collection View Cell**

```
@interface ArticleCell ()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pageImages;
@end

@implementation ArticleCell

- (void)setArticle:(Article *)article {
    _article = article;

    self.pageImages = [self.article.images valueForKeyPath:@"URL"];

    NSUInteger pageCount = [self.pageImages count];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;
    self.pageControl.hidden = (pageCount == 1);

    for (NSInteger page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.frame = frame;
        [imageView setImageWithURL:self.pageImages[page]];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize  = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageImages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you generally do not want to create properties that have side-effects like you have with your `article` property. Instead, delete `setArticle` and create a `-(void)configureForArticle:(Article *)article` method that you call, which can then do all the necessary code and set the `article` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example project can be found here: http://www.filedropper.com/collectionviewtest

Implement this as a public method in your ArticleCell:

```
- (void)cleanForReuse
{
   [[self.scrollView subviews]
               makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
   [super prepareForReuse];
   self.pageImages = nil;
}
```

Then update your code to call cleanForReuse before reusing the cell:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"articleCell";

    ArticleCell *cell = 
           [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier 
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell cleanForReuse];
    cell.article = [self.latestNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code erases my scrollViews if I scroll back up after new ones get generated.

Comment: @Chris You have something else going on then. This code is working in my test project.

Comment: I updated my code with the NSObject I have ("Article") which parses my JSON strings incase that makes a difference.

Comment: Deleting and recreating the subviews defeats much of the point of cell reuse.

Comment: @AaronBrager You are mistaken. The point of reuse is to minimize the memory churn that occurs if you have to continually re-init a cell object over and over again and improve scrolling performance that would occur otherwise because of the delay in creating a new cell object for each row. Reuse has nothing to do with the content of the cell. In fact, if you never remove the scrollView's subViews you'll be doubling the number of subViews in it for each row.

Comment: Updated the code to ensure the scrollView's `contentSize` is reset to zero (not strictly necessary) and added `prepareForReuse` to ensure the images array is released before reuse.

Comment: You won't be doubling the subviews if you don't add them each time around.

Comment: (I'm saying a better design would reduce memory churn even further by reusing the image views.)

Comment: @Chris I've included a working project demoing the functionality your question asked for.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out and helping me. It works perfect now.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons The point of reuse is NOT to minimize the memory churn. Alloc's themselves are fast enough and can optimize memory layout well. The purpose is not to create the whole object again ( init's), all its subviews, positioning and layout. This is important especially if you get your cells from xib's/storyboards, because decoder takes ages to get your cell right. Speed, not memory is the main reason for reusing - try fat cells full of subviews (without reusing) on iphone 4 which has 512MB of ram and you'll see how sluggish it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because the cells are being reused (which is a good thing for performance reasons).

When you have old content that will need to be removed from a cell when it gets reused, you will need to remove it in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:.

In your case, you will want to call removeFromSuperview on all of the imageViews that you added to the scrollView before adding the new imageViews.

You can also do some reuse preparation in the UICollectionViewCell method prepareForReuse. However, for performance reasons in UITableViewCells Apple recommends that "you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state.". Presumably, this same recommendation applies to UICollectionViewCells.

Comment: Call removeFromSuperview on each of the imageViews that you added to your scrollView. You may want to have an array property to store them in to make them easier to access.

Comment: Do not use `prepareForReuse` in this way. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content. For example, alpha, editing, and selection state.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard this before. I don't really understand how it could be significantly more resource intensive to do something in prepareForReuse than doing it in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: though. Either way, you'll need to reset the state of a cell before it gets reused. Do you happen to know of any good write ups on this topic? I couldn't find anything relevant in my search.

Comment: Apple points it out in the docs for `UITableViewCell`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW33 . It should be noted that they don't make the same comment for `UICollectionReusableView`, but they do indicate "Subclasses can override this method to assign any new **data** to the view" which would seem to indicate a similar approach (no UI changes).

Comment: Deleting and recreating the subviews defeats much of the point of cell reuse.  For example, I'd set a UIImageView's `image` to `nil`, but reuse the UIImageView the next time the cell comes around.

Comment: The reason I didn't recommend setting the image properties to nil is that I assumed, based on the posted code, that the number of imageViews varied per cell.